# I need to SELECT records from a table based on a COUNT function in SQL

Tags: sql, select, count

I have four tables:

```
  PAINTING            GALLERY             ARTIST              PAINTED
- PAINTING_TITLE    - GALLERY_ID        - ARTIST_ID         - PAINTED_CODE
- PAINTING_ID       - GALLERY_NAME      - ARTIST_LAST       - ARTIST_ID
                                        - ARTIST_FIRST      - PAINTING_ID
```

The PAINTED table keeps track of the painting painted by each artist. Some paintings are painted by more than one artist. 
I want to return a list of the paintings that have been painted by two artists.

```
SELECT PAINTING.PAINTING_TITLE AS TITLE, 
   GALLERY.GALLERY_NAME AS GALLERY, 
   ARTIST.ARTIST_FIRST AS ARTISTFIRST, 
   ARTIST.ARTIST_LAST AS ARTISTLAST
FROM PAINTING, GALLERY, PAINTED, ARTIST
WHERE PAINTING.GALLERY_ID = GALLERY.GALLERY_ID
AND PAINTING.PAINTING_ID = PAINTED.PAINTING_ID
AND ARTIST.ARTIST_ID = PAINTED.ARTIST_ID
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PAINTED, PAINTING, ARTIST
WHERE PAINTING.GALLERY_ID = GALLERY.GALLERY_ID
AND PAINTING.PAINTING_ID = PAINTED.PAINTING_ID
AND ARTIST.ARTIST_ID = PAINTED.ARTIST_ID) = 2;
```

This does not return the results I need. Do you have any ideas about how to select only the paintings that have two artists?

I'm using Access SQL, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` instead of inner `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
    PAINTING.PAINTING_TITLE AS TITLE, 
    GALLERY.GALLERY_NAME AS GALLERY
FROM
    PAINTING,
    GALLERY,
    PAINTED
WHERE
        PAINTING.GALLERY_ID = GALLERY.GALLERY_ID
    AND
        PAINTING.PAINTING_ID = PAINTED.PAINTING_ID
GROUP BY
    PAINTING.PAINTING_TITLE,
    GALLERY.GALLERY_NAME
HAVING
    COUNT(PAINTED.ARTIST_ID) = 2
```

Comment: I'm not expert in Access SQL... but shouldn't that condition be moved to a `having` clause?

Comment: @canon sure it should. Nicely spotted.

Comment: Nice solution, but it doesn't list the artist's names next to the painting. Do you know how I can get this aspect working?